# Gap between quartz upstand and wall

Tags: quartz

I have just had quartz worktops fitted inc upstands.  The gap between the upstands and the wall is up to 1/2 inch.  I realise that the walls are not straight and can see how this might impact on the upstands, but surely this would be spotted prior to installing?  Any ideas on a solution? Many many thanks!

Comment: A 1/2 inch gap is just very bad workmanship.  Installers measure and check the wall as one of the first things before even starting the countertop.  The upstands(back splashes) should meet the wall with very little gap, maybe a 1/16.  Get them back to do it right or have them pay someone else.

Comment: Thanks so much - I was starting to think I was overreacting!

Answer (score 2):

The counter top itself can be trimmed to the contour of the wall.

However the backsplash, or upstands are a uniform thickness and cannot be trimmed as to fit the contours of the wall.   If the wall is cut at the "highspots" the exposed edge of the backsplash will be very uneven and the results will be less that satisfying. The backsplash is not especially flexable, so making it meet the unevenness of the wall at variances of 1/2 inch is not feasible
.
This is a matter of the wall being very wavy.  If there is blame to be attached it should go to the drywall and framing crews as well as the counter template people for not noticing and letting the homeowner know that there will be an issue.

Without a complex rebuild of the wall, the answer may be to remove the backsplash ( upstand) and tile from counter to under the cabinets.

Comment: Thanks so much - they are suggesting having a plasterer try and plaster (then feather it out) at the worse spot (the 1/2 gap).  I was trying to avoid tiles too! Might be the best option though.  Thanks so much (wish I had stuck to something cheaper now 

Comment: Without tile, smoothing the wall with plaster is the best answer.

Comment: Don't even need to remove the "upstands"—you could just tile from the top of the upstand to the bottom of the cabinet, using additional thinset to flatten the wall.

Comment: Thanks so much - the company that arranged it all are having a plasterer look at it - thanks for the info - lets me know some options. Really grateful.